# Make a form that will send email to all the authors in selected category

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

Is there a way by which i can make a contact form in which user can choose a category from a drop down list and write a message. Then all the authors of the selected category will get an email with the message the user wrote?

Comment: i am afraid , contact form 7 doesn't provide such kind of functionality.You will need to code your form your self :(